# Adding a vector graphic in to a matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector-graphics

For *png* images I could use:

```
ax.imshow(plt.imread('./image.png'))
```

It is possible to use something similar but for *svg* or *pdf* images?

Comment: Not with pure matplotlib. But you can try to convert svg or pdf to png first and then load it. This would e.g. be possible through inkscape.

Comment: I'm going to try Inkscape, even though I rather prefer to stay on matplotlib

Comment: For the imshow strategy, I noticed that the interpolation used (in my case 'None'), make a big difference in the final resolution. I could make it good enough for my purposes.